# "Advanced" Edit and Continue?

Tags: asp.net, compilation

Alright, I've been searching forever and can't find the answer to this.

So on my work computer I run Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2005.  I have a ASP.NET project (2.0) and let's say I hit F5 and start debugging.  Now, once a page is done rendering I can edit the content or the codebehind code of the page without it throwing any error messages (just like if the project was stopped).  Then if I save the file and hit refresh on the current debugging browser, it'll take a minute to recompile the project automatically and then refresh with the recompiled code.  I can ONLY change the code in the ASP.NET project, not any class libraries that the ASP.NET project is dependent upon.  I can also set breakpoints and it'll hit them (so it's not like the debugger is not attached or something).

Now on my home computer, I run Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010. I have an ASP.NET project (4.0) and let's say I hit F5 and start debugging.  Now, it doesn't matter if the page it done rendering or not - I cannot change ANY of the code behind, although I can change the content.  If I attempt to I get a message saying

"Changes are not allowed while code is running or if the option 'Break all processes when one process breaks' is disabled.  The options can be enabled in Tools, Options, Debugging."

That being said, if I put a break point, refresh the page and hit the breakpoint THEN I can change the code and then hit F5 to continue.

**So my question is** - what EXACTLY do I need to do to get it to work like my work computer?  It's REALLY annoying to have to stop the project or be clicking breakpoints all over to edit one little piece of code (especially when I'm so used to not having to do that at work).  Is this some change in Visual Studio 2010 or something?  From what I've read, how it's working at home is the real "Edit and Continue", but I can't figure out what to call it on how it works with my work pc.

**Another difference (might be of help):**
I set it up so that my IIS goes to the project folder, and then run the project outside of the debugger on both my work and home machines.

Now on my work machine I can make a change to the code and when I hit refresh on the non-debugged browser it'll do the same pause for recompile and then refresh the screen.

On my home machine if I make a change to the code and save it and then refresh the non-debugged browser it will not recompile the code.

So this makes me think it's some IIS setting in the end to make it auto-recompile?  It clearly doesn't seem to have anything to do with VS since I'm not even going through the VS debugger to access to code at that point.

Comment: You quoted a message that's being displayed; is the option that it references enabled on your home machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just my thoughts: maybe you use on the work **WebSite** project, but at home **WebApplication**. In case of application all code will be compiled in the single DLL and changes should be recompiled first. In case of WebSite - each page compiles in different DLL and you can chage any of the page and it will recompile it.

Comment: It is a good thought, but no - they are both a WebApplication.  I had thought of that at one point before as well, alas it's not that simple. =/  Unless there is some fundamental difference in the way a .NET 4.0 WebApplication compiles "on the fly" versus a .NET 2.0 WebApplication that I'm unaware of